# flutter, "Error reading from camera" with qr_mobile_vision and ios

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

few days ago i've started to learn flutter, i wanna build an example app with a barcode reader (the second element of the bottomNavigationBar must be my barcode reader)

i've switch between various plugin for barcode but none of the previus seems works (app just crash when i install the package).

anyway, i've found (maybe) a good package: qr_mobile_vision.

i've write this code:

```dart
class _ProductState extends State<Product> {
  String barcode = "";
  Container child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int currentPage = 0;

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0.0,
          centerTitle: false,
          title: Text(
            'asdfasdf',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: _getPage(currentPage),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: FancyBottomNavigation(
          tabs: [
            TabData(iconData: Icons.home, title: "Home"),
            TabData(iconData: Icons.search, title: "Search"),
            TabData(iconData: Icons.shopping_cart, title: "Basket")
          ],
          onTabChangedListener: (position) {
            setState(() {
              currentPage = position;
            });
            print(position);
          },
        ));
  }

  _getPage(int page) {
    switch (page) {
      case 1:
        return new Container(
          constraints: new BoxConstraints.loose(new Size(600, 600)),
          child: new QrCamera(qrCodeCallback: (code) {
            print(code);
          }),
        );
        break;
      default:
        return new Container(child: new Text('Others tab'));
    }
  }
}
```

but when i go to the tab with barcode reader (at position 1) app crash with:

```
flutter: PlatformException(Error -11814, AVFoundationErrorDomain, Cannot Record)
flutter: Error reading from camera: PlatformException(Error -11814, AVFoundationErrorDomain, Cannot Record)
flutter: PlatformException(Error -11814, AVFoundationErrorDomain, Cannot Record)
flutter: Error reading from camera: PlatformException(Error -11814, AVFoundationErrorDomain, Cannot Record)
flutter: 1
flutter: 1
flutter: PlatformException(Error -11814, AVFoundationErrorDomain, Cannot Record)
flutter: Error reading from camera: PlatformException(Error -11814, AVFoundationErrorDomain, Cannot Record)
```

i've also added the "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" in info.plist...

i don't know what to do, i'm really new into flutter and i'm stuck at this point...any help?

Comment: Open info.plist under Runner app(iOS) and Add Camera Usage permission:
 <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>App will be using camera to scan QRCode</string>